# How do I *really* destroy an instance of jssor?

Tags: slideshow, jssor

I am allowing a user to dynamically create jssor slideshows each with their own image library.  I also allow the user to delete slideshows along with their image libraries.  This is a dynamic editor that avoids page reloading (an important point).

If I use `.remove()` to delete the slideshow container the user sees it disappear and while that appears to be the desired result there's a hidden problem.

Because the directory of images has also been deleted the browser's javascript console is generating a continuous stream of **not found** errors for the thumb images.  In other words, though it appears to be completely removed the jssor code is still trying to retrieve images.  I've read all the documentation and there doesn't appear to be any actual destructor for jssor.  JavaScript `delete()` is not an answer.

Since this is a dynamic editor the user must be able to create and delete jssor objects at will *without page reloading*.  Is there any way to **really** destroy the jssor object?

Answer (score 0):

I've solve my own problem... it was simple enough.  Simply put the slideshow in Pause before deleting it.  This stops the image accessing and stops the bandwidth consumption.